# read an image from windows with imread

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

i want to read an image from my windows with imread in matlab. my image name is "chest.jpg" but when i read I = imread('chest.jpg'); it shows errors :
File "chest.jpg" does not exist.
and
fullname = get_full_filename(filename);

how can I read my image from my folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you image is in 'project_folder/another_folder/.../' you must use

```
imread('project_folder/another_folder/.../chest.jpg')
```

I suggest to use a relative path if the image is inside the script folder or in some internal folder. If it is in an independent path you can use an absolute path.

Comment: now i use this path an it workded imread('C:\Users\asus\Desktop\DIPLAB2\chest.jpg');

Comment: but i want to use with a simple adress. is there any way to show it with shoter path?

Comment: Which is your script path?